# PHP file upload is creating filenames starting with "PHP" and with .tmp extension

Tags: php, symfony, file-upload

I am using PHP (Symfony2) in my project which has image upload feature. Inside controller:

```
if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest() && $request->isMethod('POST')) {
    $index=(int)$request->request->get('index');

    $image_file = $request->files->get('shop_bundle_managementbundle_posttype')['images'][$index]['file'];

    $image= new Image();

    $image->setFile($image_file);
    $image->setSubDir('hg');
    $image->upload();
    $em->persist($image);
    $em->flush();
}
```

I use a class `UploadFileMover` that handle the file upload. I didn't write the following code but as I understand, an MD5 hash will be created  from the original file name and used as filename. But the instance of `UploadedFile` contains a file name like "PHP"+number.tmp, not the original as stored in computer filesystem.

class UploadFileMover {

```
 public function moveUploadedFile(UploadedFile $file, $uploadBasePath,$relativePath) 
    {
        $originalName = $file->getFilename();

        $targetFileName = $relativePath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $originalName;

        $targetFilePath = $uploadBasePath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $targetFileName;

        $ext = $file->getExtension();

        $i=1;
        while (file_exists($targetFilePath) && md5_file($file->getPath()) != md5_file($targetFilePath)) {
            if ($ext) {
                $prev = $i == 1 ? "" : $i;
                $targetFilePath = $targetFilePath . str_replace($prev . $ext, $i++ . $ext, $targetFilePath);

            } else {
                $targetFilePath = $targetFilePath . $i++;
            }
        }

        $targetDir = $uploadBasePath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $relativePath;

        if (!is_dir($targetDir)) {
        $ret = mkdir($targetDir, umask(), true);
        if (!$ret) {
        throw new \RuntimeException("Could not create target directory to move temporary file into.");
        }
        }
        $file->move($targetDir, basename($targetFilePath));

        return str_replace($uploadBasePath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, "", $targetFilePath);
}

}
```

This class is instanciated when an image is uploaded. In other words, I have an Entity `Image` that has a method `upload`. Inside entity class:

```
public function upload()
{
    if (null === $this->getFile()) {
        return;
    }

    $uploadFileMover = new UploadFileMover();
    $this->path = $uploadFileMover->moveUploadedFile($this->file, self::getUploadDir(),$this->subDir);

    $this->file = null;
}
```

I var_dumped the filename all across the different steps but I cannot figure out where it is transformed to PHP16653.tmp.

Can it be related to an APACHE related configuration? Your help is appreciated. I really did a lot  of research for similar issue in the web to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was created by the line:

```
$originalName = $file->getFilename();
```

Use:

```
$originalName = $file->getClientOriginalName();
```

instead.